# Where did Naruto get his money from?

Tags: naruto

Well, I know this is kind of a weird question.

**In episode 176 of Naruto Shippuden**, when the village's history is shown, we see that everyone hated Naruto, and even his homeroom teacher (Iruka) didn't understood him.

He was upset, and Teuchi of Ichiraku Ramen asked him to have some ramen, but he said **"I didn't have money for it"**.

I thought a lot and was unable to figure out where he got his money from? He didn't have his missions at that time.

Comment: i cannot confirm it now , but i am sure it is third hokage , later he got from his mission

Comment: @mirroroftruth Well, I'm also not sure of it too, but when Iruka parents died, they showed that the Third was there for Iruka. But not in the case of naruto.

Comment: As you know about naruto parents so , they must have left something which was supervised by Third.

Comment: If that's the case, there can be many possibilities.

Comment: that why i can't confirm, but by looking only third among elder help naruto, so he is only one , unless there is bank or some department that give money to orphans

Comment: I remember in an episode, Hiruzen gave money to naruto for monthly expenses before leaving Naruto's house. They were discussing about who Naruto's parents are? I am not sure about the episode, but it was during the initial stage of Naruto series.

Comment: @KaguyaOtsutsuki then find that episode , write an answer mention the episode or you can add chapter of manga also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR** The Third Hokage, Sarutobi Hiruzen, looked after Naruto, in accordance with the Fourth Hokage's wish to have the village see Naruto as a hero.

Early in the series, Sarutobi mentions how the Fourth Hokage sealed the Kyuubi inside Naruto, and died wishing that the village would treat Naruto as a hero. Much later, it is also revealed that:

> Sarutobi personally witnessed the Fourth Hokage, Namikaze Minato, use the Shiki Fuijin technique to assist in sealing the Kyuubi inside Naruto. Sarutobi remarks about Minato making his own son a Jinchuriki to save the village. In the process, Naruto also became an orphan minutes after he was born. (Chapter 504)
>  
>  
>  [image: Sarutobi]

Sarutobi saw the Fourth Hokage's deed as a heroic sacrifice (especially in the light of the spoiler-text above), and took up the responsibility of fulfilling the Fourth Hokage's wish. Naturally, that includes paying for the orphan child's expenses until he is old enough.

Along the same lines, it was also mentioned that Sarutobi banned any discussion of the Kyuubi incident and severely punished anyone who disobeyed. Most other people either hated Naruto or were indifferent towards him, as he remarks multiple times later on during the series. Thus, nobody besides Sarutobi could possibly care to pay for Naruto's expenses.<sup>1</sup>

Hence, although nobody explicitly stated that the Third Hokage looked after Naruto's expenses (room rent, food, clothes, etc.), it is obvious that this is what happened.

---

<sup>1</sup> This also leads to one of the many plotholes in Naruto's childhood story: Naruto has said a few times that Iruka-sensei was the first person who cared for him, and before then, his life was a hell of loneliness. Why didn't Sarutobi treat him with a bit more warmth from the beginning, *especially* when he knew who Naruto's parents were?

Comment: Last question is that for the plot hole then ,why, because  Naruto is not only orphan child in Konoha and if 3rd had shown(internally he did) more warm feeling toward him, story would have been different, why Naruto with special care , why not other orphan, this may reveal Naruto's parent true identity

Comment: I am not saying he should have treated Naruto with any "special" care, but just enough care to make him feel like he is not lonely. Sarutobi knows that Kyuubi is sealed inside Naruto, so at least fill him with some positive thoughts. We have seen what happened with Gaara because everyone hated him. As the Hokage, he would definitely know that if the Jinchuriki is filled with hatred, it is easy for the Bijuu to control him or break loose.

Answer (score 1):

As we all know that Third Hokage, Sarutobi was always there for orphans especially those whose parents were shinoubi and had died for Konoha , such a case can be seen for Iruka when he was child and had lost his parents as in Episode 144 of Shonen Jump ,in Mizuki's flashback. Same was the case with Naruto for his father , The Fourth Hokage had also used the forbidden jutsu, died and made his son a jinchurikki as to save Konoha that is why Naruto was given all economical support but the caring and love could not be given to him by Sarutobi because hokage is always busy in paper work and assembling of ninjas and could not spare time for that, the proof for that thing is when Lady Tsunade is made hokage she has bundles and bundles of paperwork to do so. That is how Naruto has money but still spends his life in Loneliness and Despair.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hfUGINaiauM

Go to 4:32 the third hokage is shown giving Naruto his expenses

Comment: Welcome to Anime & Manga Stack Exchange. Looks like this could be a good answer, but as of current writing, it still lacks detail. Could you also provide which episode that specific scene come from? Please refer to [answer] and consider taking a quick [tour] to understand more how this site works. Thanks!